# Open subtitles characters encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET', url:'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-19af0c55/sid-ste0uene5gb0jh8dsrma7tcq15/1955127527.srt'};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Normal download using the browser yields a correct encoding of the file. Using postman to download the file, I get corrupt document with incorrect encoding.

Example: Je suis d�sol�e. Je sais

Without success, I tried to set 'Content-Type' header to utf8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    http.get(sub.url, function(res) {
      res.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('win1252')).collect(function(err, decodedBody) {
        srt2vtt(decodedBody, function(err, vttData) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err)

          let filename = 'sub-' + sub.lang + 'vtt'
          let vttPath = path.join(dir, filename)
          fs.writeFileSync(vttPath, vttData)
          cb(vttPath)
    })
  });
});
```

https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Use-Buffers-when-decoding
I used streaming support to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it. you need to do `npm install --save iconv-lite`

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET', url:'http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/filead/src-api/vrf-19af0c55/sid-ste0uene5gb0jh8dsrma7tcq15/1955127527.srt'};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    var formattedData = iconv.decode(body, 'iso-8859-1');
    console.log(formattedData);

});
```

you can check out https://github.com/request/request/issues/118. he suggests to use `iconv-lite`.

Comment: The api responds with and array, and object with lang 'fr' is encoded using 'CP1252'. I proceeded like you said, with several encoding but no way.

Comment: It works for me. I get the proper data. this is what it prints `Je suis dýsolýe. Je sais`

Comment: Should be 'désolée'. I get another workaround, also using iconv-lite.

Comment: Thats great. Happy that you were able to find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help.